# Wordpress check if there is widget in widget position

Tags: php, wordpress-theming, wordpress

I have created widget position in wordpress theme:

```
    <div class="row">
        <?php if ( dynamic_sidebar('Top')) ?>
    </div>
```

if there is not any widget active in this position then I want to hide whole code.

is there any code for wordpress like in joomla

`<?php if($this->countModules('Top')): ?>`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`is_active_sidebar` should do the job, at least the WP source-code looks as if the function would check, if the sidebar is empty:

```
/**
* Whether a sidebar is in use.
*
* @since 2.8
*
* @param mixed $index Sidebar name, id or number to check.
* @return bool true if the sidebar is in use, false otherwise.
*/
function is_active_sidebar( $index ) {
   $index = ( is_int($index) ) ? "sidebar-$index" : sanitize_title($index);
   $sidebars_widgets = wp_get_sidebars_widgets();
   if ( !empty($sidebars_widgets[$index]) )
           return true;
   return false;
}
```